# telethon forward messages without a specific word

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am using a telegram bot that forwards messages from a certain channel to any other channel I am on, but I want it to forward these messages without a word, for example the message ends with "flowers", I want the bot to forward the message without the word "flowers".

```
    @BotzHubUser.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, chats=FROM)) 
async def sender_bH(event):
    for i in TO:
        try:
            await BotzHubUser.send_message(
                i,
                event.message
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/updates.html) try :

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'flower' not in event.raw_text:
        await event.reply('hi!')
```